# Where I can download or regenerate My Microsoft certificate?

Tags: .net

I'm not sure if I should ask this question on this forum.

In 2010 I pass 'Microsoft .NET Framework, Application Development Foundation (70-536)' exam. This is really old exam.

I'm tired with login to different subdomain '*.microsoft.com' and search for this certificate. Where I can find functionality to download certificate? It is possible that the data about passed exam is missing on My account?

Where is support for that stuffs?

Sorry for My English.

Comment: Maybe contact the Microsoft support!? What should we do with your certification id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct url is:  mcp.microsoft.com

I must migrate my account using MC ID.